# Which digest algorithm to use with creating a public/private key pair

Tags: encryption, php, public-key-infrastructure

I'm generating a Public/Private key pair in PHP with the following:

```
<?php
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
 );

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);

// Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);

// Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
?>
```

But I'm doubting about what to choose for the `digest_alg` variable. What is the 'best' to use here? Where can I choose from? And last but not least, what does it do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`digest_alg` is not used by `openssl_pkey_new()` but by [`openssl_csr_new()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-csr-new.php): the latter creates a public/private key pair *and* wraps the public key into a certificate request, which is self-signed (with the newly generated private key). That signature involves using a hash function, hence the parameter.

`openssl_pkey_new()` entails no signature and thus has no need for a "hash function" parameter.

For `openssl_csr_new()`, your sensible choices are between SHA-256 (robust, recommended, efficient) and SHA-1 (theoretically less robust, no longer recommended, a bit faster, and, more importantly, supported everywhere). IE 8.0 on Windows XP (with all updates) supports SHA-256 for certificates (I have tried it yesterday), so I incline to assert that SHA-256 is now sufficiently well supported that it can be recommended "by default".

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation; the php-documentation is not very clear about this. Which of the `config_vars` can I use to create the best/robust private/public key-pair with `openssl_pkey_new()`